# How do I Embed an image in the body of an HTML eMail

Tags: image, email, html-email

I'm trying to send a system generated eMail, where I'm including an image in the body of the eMail.  I'm receiving a "Red X" instead of the image when the message is sent with the following HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN""http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
      <html>
      <head>
      <title>Test Mailing</title>
      <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
      </head>
      <body><p>
    Text right before the HP image.</p>
<p>
    <img alt="Harry Potter" src="data:image/jpeg;base64, /9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEAYABgAAD/2wBDAAIBAQIBAQICAgICAgICAwUDAwMDAwYEBAMFBwYHBwcGBwcICQsJCAgKCAcHCg0KCgsMDAwMBwkODw0MDgsMDAz/2wBDAQICAgMDAwYDAwYMCAcIDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAz/wAARCABkAJoDASIAAhEBAxEB/8QAHwAAAQUBAQEBAQEAAAAAAAAAAAECAwQFBgcICQoL/8QAtRAAAgEDAwIEAwUFBAQAAAF9AQIDAAQRBRIhMUEGE1FhByJxFDKBkaEII0KxwRVS0fAkM2JyggkKFhcYGRolJicoKSo0NTY3ODk6Q0RFRkdISUpTVFVWV1hZWmNkZWZnaGlqc3R1dnd4eXqDhIWGh4iJipKTlJWWl5iZmqKjpKWmp6ipqrKztLW2t7i5usLDxMXGx8jJytLT1NXW19jZ2uHi4+Tl5ufo6erx8vP09fb3+Pn6/8QAHwEAAwEBAQEBAQEBAQAAAAAAAAECAwQFBgcICQoL/8QAtREAAgECBAQDBAcFBAQAAQJ3AAECAxEEBSExBhJBUQdhcRMiMoEIFEKRobHBCSMzUvAVYnLRChYkNOEl8RcYGRomJygpKjU2Nzg5OkNERUZHSElKU1RVVldYWVpjZGVmZ2hpanN0dXZ3eHl6goOEhYaHiImKkpOUlZaXmJmaoqOkpaanqKmqsrO0tba3uLm6wsPExcbHyMnK0tPU1dbX2Nna4uPk5ebn6Onq8vP09fb3+Pn6/9oADAMBAAIRAxEAPwD9/KKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKACiiigArz/46ftY/Cz9l/8Asv8A4WX8S/AHw7/tzzf7N/4SfxDaaR/aHlbPN8n7RInmbPNj3bc7fMTONwr4A/4Ogv8Agrz47/4Jefs4+AdI+FN7/YfxG+J+q3H2bW5dLt7+HS9OsFhe62LOWjFxJJc2iLvhlTymufuSCJq/FHwN/wAERPFvi/4L2vx7/ac+MGn/AAo0T4p2kviHw080TeMfF/j2e4ggv0uhbRToixzpcNvnurpHjmKLMiCZZKAP6bf+HsX7LP8A0ct8AP8Aw4ekf/JFH/D2L9ln/o5b4Af+HD0j/wCSK/kr/Zn/AGSfCXiq48UQ65FqGtDTbmO0hneGSzjjkUyeYEKTEPn5M7hlQV/vV6Fr/wDwT5+Hms+V9nGt6V5ed32W73ebnGN3mh+mOMY6nOeMeDi+I8Jhq7w9W911tptfv+h+z8N+BXEme5PSzrASp8lS9ouUlPSTjs4cvS697VW66H9SX/D2L9ln/o5b4Af+HD0j/wCSKP8Ah7F+yz/0ct8AP/Dh6R/8kV/MBD+wp8MvNXOi3BGRwb645/J6tn9hX4XspH/COsMjgjULrj85a4XxjgV9mX3L/M+rp/Rb4tmrqth//A6n/wAqP6dP+HsX7LP/AEct8AP/AA4ekf8AyRXoHwL/AGsfhZ+1B/an/CtPiX4A+In9h+V/aX/CMeIbTV/7P83f5XnfZ5H8vf5Um3djd5b4ztNfyn+Hf+CKegfEyWy1a1+IWo+GdFvp28+3/sNdUmtEEzKxjJuYd+EA2qxGSOX5yPVP2l/+DYj4ufsp/AD/AIaL+C3xe8P+OvC3gfQI/G7XkXm+GvE2lS2rtNO9vHHLPAJLOOMTFxeJKHhlRIzIiCT3sHmWHxS/cvXsfj3FfAWdcOy/4U6VottKSacW12tqvmk/I/qcor8oP+DUj/gq58R/+CiP7OPjjwV8UJf7f8QfBf8Asq1t/FU07Pf69Z3i3YiS8BHz3EP2NlNxu3TLIhcGVJJZv1fruPjgooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKAPwo/4PRvhRqPxh8Rfsx6Zpk1lBPBbeLbpmunZUKhtCUgFVY5y47etfAeoSeOfiJ4N8Hx+Kte/ty58J+F9M8NaerSny7OysrVIILeFdqqiKFJ6Dczu7Zd3Y/qd/wdWf2f8A8Jb+z35n/IV+yeKPs/3v9Tv0Xzf9n73k9efTvX5qaT/yCrb/AK5J/IV8nmuc4jD4l0qeytuj+l/DXwqyPO8gp5hj+Z1JuS92VrWbSuraPS/o0zjv2dPBuo+FtJ8SR6hb/Z2u/EF1dRfOr7o2WPa3yk46Hg816J9j9/0pumQrDE5UY3OWbHc4FWt9fn2YYmdbETqy3bP7V4LyHDZXkmGy+g24U42Tk9bedkl+BW+zbGBznB9KmHNKTlqdt+auFtvc+qjBR+E99+Bv/JL9N/3pv/R0lfWXgT44Tap/wSV/a7+H19eeZ/Znwq8TavpMLiV3SF9KukuVDElFjWQwsEG0lp5G+bJ2/JvwOGPhfpv+9N/6Okq38Y7i+T4IePbXTrz+z59Y8Kaxo7z+SsuyG7sJ7Wb5W4OYpnHYjOQQcEfWZVi/q1aFXp19P61P528RuGf7eynE5cvjd3DynF3Xpf4W+ibL/wDwYx/83Rf9yp/7mq/f6vwJ/wCDHvSbjQNX/assbuPyrqym8LQTJuDbHU62rDIyDgg9Div32r9PTTV0f56ThKEnCas1o0+gUUUUEhRRRQAUUUUAFFFFABRRRQB+Df8AweseNrj4deNv2S9athvksJvFblMgeahGiq6ZIONyFlzjIzkcivnrW/BsPi74HeD/ABbo++4jm0Kxkl2RY8yA26ssxBw2QCAcgnbjoFNfsV/wXQ/4IyaF/wAFhv2cbDTY9V/4Rr4m+BPtV34M1iaSQ2CSzrF59peRLnNvP5EIMqqZYWjR1DqJIZvwq+Dn7P8A+05/wTq8Cat4M+Knw18W+G9G8N3yxrLqelJeeHp1vIfOWGHUYC8Ex3GRmWOY7XYq3zB1HzPEmD56SxEd46P0/wCA/wAz+gfATimWGzCpklZ+5W96PlOK1/8AAorX/CvM2rNcWv1yaftJripvHl1JcO6QWsIdiQiB9qA9hlicD3JPvTf+E7vfSH8m/wAa/O54Nyk5XP7jwnEdOjRjSdPZW3O4CnNPVdxrhP8AhO730h/Jv8a6Hwn8f9S8I6c9smlaBeh5DLvu7VpHGQBgHeOOP1NR9Rfc6lxXTX/Lt/efTfwc0+bTPhtpkc6bHKvKBkH5XkZ1PHqrA/jWv8RfAOveM/2ffi1f6BFZyS+DPAWueKLprqTbFHBZ2UkjZA+ZizbECrzlxkqoZl+UfHn/AAUZvvhT4fN1qcXhq1jjjPkWyQyebcbcDZEnmjcfmUegyCSBzXH+FvEX7e3/AAUn0G88N/BfwT8WLD4U/E/zIt+i6e+i6Fr0NrDeW80V1rEnlwtCwe7je3kuvJeTbGVeRUr6jJ8rniJpyXuLd/ofz34oeIuFyLB1aWHmni5/DHdx5vtS7JLVX3dtLXa+4/8Agx71a41/V/2rL67k826vZvC08z7Qu92OtsxwMAZJPQYr99q/OD/g28/4Iya7/wAEmP2cfEepeO9V8/4m/Fj7Bd69o9rJHLYeG4rRbj7NaLKufOuB9rmM0qsYtxVIwyx+dN+j9foqSSsj+F5zlOTnN3b1bfUKKKKCQooooAKKKKACiiigAooooAKKKKAPG/Gf/BPr4NePdUS8vvAOkQSxxCELpzzabEVBJyY7d40LZY/MRuIwM4AAyP8Ah2J8Dv8AoSP/ACs6h/8AH697orleBwzd3Tj9yPo6XGOf04KnTx1ZJbJVZpf+lHgn/DsT4Hf9CR/5WdQ/+P1f8Mf8E6Pgt4R1yDULXwJYSz2+7al7dXN9AdylTuhmkeNuCcblODgjBANe2UULAYZO6px+5DnxnxBOLhPHVmno06s9f/JivpWlWug6XbWNjbQWdlZxLBb28EYjigjUBVRFGAqgAAADAAqxRRXUfONuTu9wooooEFFFFABRRRQAUUUUAFFFFABRRRQAUUUUAFFFFABRRRQAUUUUAFFFFABRRRQAUUUUAf/Z"/>
</p>
<p>
    Text right after the image.</p>
<p>
    &nbsp;</p>
</body></html>
```

With the above HTML, I get the following in my eMail:

Text right before the HP image.

Harry Potter

Text right after the image.

When I inspect my gMail contents, I show the following:

```
<div><p>
    Text right before the HP image.</p>
<p>
    <img alt="Harry Potter">
</p>
<p>
    Text right after the image.</p>
<p>
    &nbsp;</p>
</div>
```

The "alt" seems to be preserved, but the "src" seems to get dropped somehow.

As a test, I tried to send an eMail where the image is retrieved from a server.  The following code produces expected results, but it's with a linked, and not an embedded image.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN""http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
      <html>
      <head>
      <title>Test Mailing</title>
      <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
      </head>
      <body><p>
    Text right before the Oracle image.</p>
<p>
    <img src="http://oracle-base.com/images/site_logo.gif" /></p>
<p>
    Text right after the image.</p>

<p>
    &nbsp;</p>
</body></html>
```

I'm assuming my problem is with the IMG tag, but the IMG seems to follow the examples I've seen online regarding embedding an image.

Thanks for looking at this.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with the whitespace you inserted in you base64 encoding:

```
src="data:image/jpeg;base64, /9j/4AAQS...
```

should be:

```
src="data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQS...
```

and then it works.

Comment: Hi Adobe.  Thanks very much for looking at this.  I appreciate the help.  I tried removing the blank after the comma and I still get just the ALT text in the body of the email (no image).

Comment: @user3138025: that's strange. I use gmail. I send it to myself two times: one with space, and the other one without space. And the one without space shows an image. Are sure it doesn't work for you?

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest adding a hidden attachment and then referring to the embedded image in the HTML markup. See [vba email embed image not showing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27544091/vba-email-embed-image-not-showing) for more information

Comment: Thanks Eugene,I'm sending this via Oracle's UTL_SMTP.  Do you happen to have any examples using that package?  Phil