# Copy and Forward Email With Images in Body

Tags: vba, outlook

I'm trying to copy the body of an email and put it into a template before the user can forward it.

Images in the body of the original email become blank boxes with red Xs inside of them.

Error message:

> The linked image cannot be displayed. The file may have been moved, renamed, or deleted. Verify that the link points to the correct file and location.

I need to copy the original images into a temp folder then reinsert them into my email.

My macro can copy the images into a temp folder. How do I put these images into the final email?

UPDATE:
I figured out how to add the images in my temp file to my email as hidden attachment. (I updated my code below). I think the problem is that the HTML image tags are still referencing the location of the images in my old email (ex: src="cid:image001.jpg@01D09693.82092260").

Will removing the "@01D09693.82092260" make the tag get the image from the current attachments? How do I do that?

```vb
Sub ForwardEmail()

    Dim Item As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim oForward As Outlook.MailItem
    Dim olAttach As Outlook.Attachments
    Dim strFileN As String

    Set Item = GetCurrentItem
    Set oForward = Application.CreateItemFromTemplate("Z:\Template.oft")

    strFileN = Dir("K:\Temp\*.*")

    With oForward
        .Subject = Item.Subject
        .HTMLBody = Item.HTMLBody & oForward.HTMLBody

        Do While Len(strFileN) > 0
            .Attachments.Add "K:\Temp\" & strFileN, olByValue, 0
            strFileN = Dir
        Loop

        .Display
        .BodyFormat = olFormatHTML
    End With
    
    Kill "K:\Temp\*.*"
        
    Set Item = Nothing
    Set oForward = Nothing

End Sub
    
Function GetCurrentItem() As Object
    Dim objApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim objAttachments As Outlook.Attachments
    Dim objSelection As Outlook.Selection
    Dim i As Long
    Dim lngCount As Long
    Dim strFile As String
    Dim strFolderpath As String
                
    Set objApp = Application
    'On Error Resume Next
    Select Case TypeName(objApp.ActiveWindow)
        Case "Explorer"
            Set GetCurrentItem = objApp.ActiveExplorer.Selection.Item(1)
        Case "Inspector"
            Set GetCurrentItem = objApp.ActiveInspector.CurrentItem
    End Select
        
    strFolderpath = "K:\Temp\"
     
    Set objAttachments = GetCurrentItem.Attachments
    lngCount = objAttachments.Count
             
    If lngCount > 0 Then
       
    ' Use a count down loop for removing items
    ' from a collection. Otherwise, the loop counter gets
    ' confused and only every other item is removed.
         
        For i = lngCount To 1 Step -1
         
            ' Get the file name.
            strFile = objAttachments.Item(i).FileName
         
            ' Combine with the path to the Temp folder.
            strFile = strFolderpath & strFile
         
            ' Save the attachment as a file.
            objAttachments.Item(i).SaveAsFile strFile
         
        Next i
    End If
            
    Set objApp = Nothing
    Set objAttachments = Nothing
    Set objSelection = Nothing
    
End Function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I solved it myself!**

I resorted to using RegEx to remove the offending Hex path in order to get the images to link to the currently attached ones. This took a quite some time with getting my regular expressions to work properly but here's the final code!

```
Sub ForwardEmail()

Dim Item As Outlook.MailItem
Dim oForward As Outlook.MailItem
Dim olAttach As Outlook.Attachments
Dim strFileN As String
Dim sBadHex As String

Set Item = GetCurrentItem
Set oForward = Application.CreateItemFromTemplate("Z:\Template.oft")

sBadHex = GetBadHex(Item.HTMLBody)
sEmailHTML = Replace(Item.HTMLBody, sBadHex, "")

strFileN = Dir("K:\Temp\*.*")

    With oForward
        .Subject = Item.Subject
        .HTMLBody = sEmailHTML & oForward.HTMLBody
        Do While Len(strFileN) > 0
            .Attachments.Add "K:\Temp\" & strFileN, olByValue, 0
            strFileN = Dir
        Loop
        '.BodyFormat = olFormatHTML <-- I don't think you need this
        .Display
    End With

Kill "K:\Temp\*.*"
Set Item = Nothing
Set oForward = Nothing

End Sub

Function GetCurrentItem() As Object
    Dim objApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim objAttachments As Outlook.Attachments
    Dim objSelection As Outlook.Selection
    Dim i As Long
    Dim lngCount As Long
    Dim strFile As String
    Dim strFolderpath As String

    Set objApp = Application
    'On Error Resume Next
    Select Case TypeName(objApp.ActiveWindow)
        Case "Explorer"
            Set GetCurrentItem = objApp.ActiveExplorer.Selection.Item(1)
        Case "Inspector"
            Set GetCurrentItem = objApp.ActiveInspector.CurrentItem
    End Select

    strFolderpath = "K:\Temp\"

    Set objAttachments = GetCurrentItem.Attachments
    lngCount = objAttachments.Count

    If lngCount > 0 Then

    ' Use a count down loop for removing items
    ' from a collection. Otherwise, the loop counter gets
    ' confused and only every other item is removed.

    For i = lngCount To 1 Step -1

    ' Get the file name.
    strFile = objAttachments.Item(i).FileName

    ' Combine with the path to the Temp folder.
    strFile = strFolderpath & strFile

    ' Save the attachment as a file.
    objAttachments.Item(i).SaveAsFile strFile

    Next i
    End If

    Set objApp = Nothing
    Set objAttachments = Nothing
    Set objSelection = Nothing

End Function

Function GetBadHex(sInput As String) As String
 Dim rImgTag As RegExp
 Set rImgTag = New RegExp
 Dim mImgTag As Object
 Dim rBadHex As RegExp
 Set rBadHex = New RegExp
 Dim mBadHex As Object


 Dim sImgTag As String
 Dim sBadHex As String

     With rImgTag
        .Pattern = "cid:image[0-9]{3}\.[a-z]{3}@[0-9A-Z]{8}\.[0-9A-Z]{8}"
     End With

     With rBadHex
        .Pattern = "@[0-9A-Z]{8}\.[0-9A-Z]{8}"
     End With

Set mImgTag = rImgTag.Execute(sInput)

If mImgTag.Count <> 0 Then
    sImgTag = mImgTag.Item(0)
End If


Set mBadHex = rBadHex.Execute(sImgTag)

If mBadHex.Count <> 0 Then
    sBadHex = mBadHex.Item(0)
End If

GetBadHex = sBadHex
Set rImgTag = Nothing
Set rBadHex = Nothing

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

The [Add](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869553(v=office.15).aspx) method of the Attachments class allows to attach files to the mail.

Also you need to set PR_ATTACH_CONTENT_ID property (DASL - http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x3712001F) on the attachment using Attachment.PropertyAccessor. Be aware, the PropertyAccessor property of the Attachment class was added in Outlook 2007.

You may find the [How do I embed image in Outlook Message in VBA?](http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/re-do-embed-image-outlook-message-vba-t3695969.html) link helpful.

See [vba email embed image not showing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27544091/vba-email-embed-image-not-showing) for the complete sample code.