# Attach jpg to Outlook Body & center

Tags: vba, outlook

I am having issues getting an email to fire with a jpg attachment that should be centered at top before text.

The `EmailBody` is defined upstream from this and the `Target` is just a name from an excel sheet (this macro is called from another macro that loops through a range).

I believe the issue is with how I am declaring outlook objects. Currenty errors out (once removing the `On Error Go To` line) at `Set oAttach = colAttach.Add("C:\Users\urdearboy\Desktop\@\Meme.jpg")`

---

**Any idea where I am going wrong? Not extremely experienced in outlook objects/properties and tried to follow post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27544091/vba-email-embed-image-not-showing) with no luck**

---

```
Sub Sender(EmailBody As String, Target As Range)

''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object

On Error GoTo BNP:

    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
    Set colAttach = OutMail.Attachments
    Set oAttach = colAttach.Add("C:\Users\urdearboy\Desktop\@\Meme.jpg")
    Set olkPA = oAttach.PropertyAccessor

    olkPA.SetProperty PR_ATTACH_CONTENT_ID, "Meme.jpg"

        With OutMail
            .SentOnBehalfOfName = "urdearboy@so.com"
            .to = Target.Offset(0, 1)
            .cc = Target.Offset(0, 2)
            .Subject = "Check Out This Meme " & Target.Offset(0, 3)
            .HTMLBody = "<p style = 'font-family:arial' >" _
                        & "<BODY><CENTER><IMG src =""cid:Meme.jpg""></CENTER></BODY>" _
                        & "Hi " & Target.Offset(0, 0) & ", " & "<br>" _
                        & EmailBody & "</p>" _
                        & "<p style = 'font-family:arial' >" & "<br>" & "Thanks, " & "<br>" _
                        & "urdearboy" & "</p>"

            'Change to .Send to actually send emails
            .Display

            Target.Offset(, -1) = "Sent"

        End With

BNP:
    Set OutApp = Nothing
    Set OutMail = Nothing

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing the constant declaration

```
Sub Sender(EmailBody As String, Target As Range)

''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object
Dim colattach As Object
Dim oAttach As Object
Dim olkPA As Object

On Error GoTo BNP:

    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
    Set colattach = OutMail.Attachments
    Set oAttach = colattach.Add("C:\Users\urdearboy\Desktop\@\Meme.jpg")
    Set olkPA = oAttach.PropertyAccessor

    Const PR_ATTACH_CONTENT_ID = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x3712001F" ' <-----This line

    olkPA.SetProperty PR_ATTACH_CONTENT_ID, "Meme.jpg"

        With OutMail
            .SentOnBehalfOfName = "urdearboy@so.com"
            .to = Target.Offset(0, 1)
            .cc = Target.Offset(0, 2)
            .Subject = "Check Out This Meme " & Target.Offset(0, 3)
            .HTMLBody = "<p style = 'font-family:arial' >" _
                        & "<BODY><CENTER><IMG src =""cid:Meme.jpg""></CENTER></BODY>" _
                        & "Hi " & Target.Offset(0, 0) & ", " & "<br>" _
                        & EmailBody & "</p>" _
                        & "<p style = 'font-family:arial' >" & "<br>" & "Thanks, " & "<br>" _
                        & "urdearboy" & "</p>"

            'Change to .Send to actually send emails
            .Display

            Target.Offset(, -1) = "Sent"

        End With

BNP:
    Set OutApp = Nothing
    Set OutMail = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: What is that constant just out of curiosity?

Comment: It's a a DASL property and outlook uses it to set/get the name of the embedded attachment