# Add image (chart) to HTMLbody

Tags: excel, vba, outlook, html-email

I am having issues with inserting image (chart) into an HTMLbody. I export the chart to another folder and then call the image path.

```
msg = "<html>123,<br/> 123 <b>" & countries & ":</b><br/>" & RangetoHTML(tablex) & s & "<img src=""cid:" & fileName & "><html\>"
```

However, after I insert the image with the above message body it shows:

[image]

And after the adjustments by correctly specifying which image, I get:

[image]

To specify the exact image I use:

```
Set myChart = wbe.Sheets("Sheet1").ChartObjects("Chart 11").Chart

Dim myPicture As String
Dim fileName As String
Dim myPath As String

myPicture = "Chart1.jpg"
myPath = "C:\qwe\"

fileName = myPath & myPicture
myChart.Export fileName
```

Whole code:

```
Sub transactional_emails()

'Create email and save it as draft
    Dim olApp As Object
    Dim olMailItm As Object
    Dim iCounter As Integer
    Dim Dest As Variant
    Dim SDest As String
    Dim source As String
    Dim oAccount As String
    Dim msg As String
    Dim tablex As Range
    Dim wbe As Workbook
    Dim las As Long
    Dim countries As String
    Dim myChart As Chart
    
    countries = "LOL"
    
    Set wbe = Workbooks(ThisWorkbook.Name)
    
    las = wbe.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(wbe.Sheets("Sheet1").Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    
    Set tablex = wbe.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:G" & las)
    
    With tablex.Borders
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .Color = vbBlack
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
    
    
    Set myChart = wbe.Sheets("Sheet1").ChartObjects("Chart 11").Chart
    
    Dim myPicture As String
    Dim fileName As String
    Dim myPath As String

    myPicture = "Chart1.jpg"
    myPath = "C:\qwe\"

    fileName = myPath & myPicture
    myChart.Export fileName
    

    'Create the Outlook application and the empty email.
    Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set olMailItm = olApp.CreateItem(0)
    
    Dim s As String
    s = Environ("appdata") & "\Microsoft\Signatures\"
    If Dir(s, vbDirectory) <> vbNullString Then s = s & Dir$(s & "*.htm") Else s = ""
    s = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").GetFile(s).OpenAsTextStream(1, -2).ReadAll
    
    msg = "<html>123,<br/> 123 <b>" & countries & ":</b><br/>" & RangetoHTML(tablex) & s & "<img src=""cid:" & myPicture & """></html>"
    
    With olMailItm
        SDest = "gal.bordelius_ext@novartis.com"
        'oAccount = "customer.service_GOC@novartis.com"
    
        .To = SDest
        .CC = "gal.bordelius_ext@novartis.com"
        .Subject = countries & " 123 " & Date
        .Attachments.Add fileName, 1, 0
        .htmlbody = msg
        .Save
    End With
    
    'Clean up the Outlook application.
    Set olMailItm = Nothing
    Set olApp = Nothing

End sub
```

Comment: If you `debug.print msg` you can see the missing quote `<img src="cid:C:\temp\Chart1.jpg><html\>` however it should just be the filename so use `"<img src=""cid:" & myPicture & """>`. Also the end tag should be `</html>`

Comment: Thank you. I am now getting that the file cannot be displayed properly. Edited the post.

Comment: Is that an Excel error or an Outlook error ?

Comment: Excel did not display any errors, so I am guessing an outlook error.

Comment: Is the chart complex ? Check the file `"C:\qwe\Chart1.jpg"` exists and opens OK then try with `myChart.Export fileName` commented out.

Comment: What is your final HTML? Is it well-formed?

Comment: Try any other sample image - does it work correctly in Outlook, i.e. displayed without a problem?

Comment: I think that the HTML should be fine (it is written above). I've tried with other images and it displays the same error. Is it possible that the problem lies within Outlook settings?

Comment: RangeToHtml creates a file with `<html>` tags so your html starts `<html>123,<br/> 123 <b>LOL:</b><br/>
<html xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"
xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel"
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">` and ends `</html>
<img src="cid:Chart1.jpg"></html>` which is not valid. However it seems to display OK for me so I guess it's your Outlook settings.

Comment: Thank you all for taking your time and reviewing my question, I've fixed it through this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27544091/vba-email-embed-image-not-showing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The source code is valid:

1. You attach an image to the mail item in Outlook:

```
.Attachments.Add fileName, 1, 0
```

2. Then you can refer to the attached image from the message body in the following way:

```
"<img src=""cid:" & myPicture & """>
```

3. Sometimes you also need to set the `PR_ATTACH_CONTENT_ID` property (DASL - `http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x3712001F`) on the attachment using `Attachment.PropertyAccessor`.

You may also consider adding some parameters like height or width. Note, the image name can't contains spaces.

When you open an email message that contains images in Microsoft Office Outlook, the image areas can be blocked. Read more about that in the [Pictures cannot be displayed and are shown as red X in Outlook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/troubleshoot/message-body/pictures-not-displayed-and-shown-as-red-x) article.

Comment: I've found your answer on this post which had the similar problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27544091/vba-email-embed-image-not-showing Thank you.

Comment: I've updated the post. Glad it helped!

Comment: Any support chart for embedded images? Am curious how many support it.